# How to put two differents version of a dependency? - Maven - Java - Spring

Tags: java, maven

I'm gonna make a hypothetical case, we suppose that we have the following Maven's dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.group1</groupId>
     <artifactId>dependency1</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.group2</groupId>
     <artifactId>dependency2</artifactId>
     <!-- This dependency needs the version 2.0 of the dependency1 -->
</dependency>
```

What happen here? We have two dependencies, one "dependency1" has the version 1.0, and "dependency2" need the version 2.0 of the first depedency internally. You could say, that I could remove remove the "dependency1" and keep the dependency2, because it already has that dependency. But if I use just the "dependency2", some methods fail.

So in conclussion: I need to use the version 1.0 of the "dependency1" in whole my project, but, when the project uses the "dependency2" I want load the version 2.0 of the "dependency1".

I'dont know if I explained it well, but, any suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion would be to just use dependency 2 and to just refactor your failing methods, personally

Comment: Sounds like a case for "welcome to [jar hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell)" - the problem is that Java would need to know which classes to use, i.e. those of v1 or those of v2. To do that you'd need different classloaders (likely in some hierarchary) and put `dependency2` into the correct one - but that's all very complex and hard to tune. Your best bet would be to make a service out of whatever uses `dependency2` and call that (e.g. via REST or some other "remote" protocol).

Comment: My suggestion will be to exclude the 'dependency1' from 'dependency2' using Maven [exclusions] (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)  and use the same version of 'dependency1' throughout the project.